# O que significa: "funções são objetos de primeira classe em JavaScript"?

Tags: javascript, funções

Várias vezes já ouvi isso: "funções são objetos de primeira classe em JavaScript". Funções serem armazenadas em variáveis e passadas em métodos e etc não foi algo que me surpreendeu  tanto no JavaScript inicialmente, pois já estava acostumado com os delegates do C#. A minha dúvida é em relação à esse termo "primeira classe", o que exatamente significa isso?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

O termo "primeira classe" significa que a função é tratada da mesma forma que qualquer tipo de valor no javascript. Por exemplo, para você atribuir um valor a uma variável, você faz assim:

```
var meuInteiro = 10;  
var minhaString = "minha string";
var minhaFuncao = function() { console.log('minha função'); }
```

Ou seja, você utilizou a mesma sintaxe nas três formas, e o javascript entende do mesmo jeito. Você também pode passar a função como parâmetros, atributos de objetos, etc, do mesmo jeito que você faz com qualquer outro tipo. 
Isso que significa "primeira classe".

--
Um ótimo artigo sobre o assunto: http://javascriptbrasil.com/2012/09/05/funcoes-de-primeira-classe/

Comment: Para completar: uma função pode retornar outra função.

Answer (score 6):

Em linguagens como Java, C# e Visual Basic, você programa tudo em classes - são elas os "cidadãos" de primeira classe. O método `Main` que inicia seu programa é membro de uma classe. Os objetos que você codifica são todos instâncias de classes que alguém escreveu. Abra sua IDE e veja... Em código C#, as únicas coisas que você escreve fora do escopo das classes são decoração (para as próprias classes), declaração de novos espaços de nome (*namespaces*) e declaração de quais espaços de nomes vai utilizar.

Em Javascript não existem classes - pelo menos não da mesma forma que há em outras linguagens.  A tipificação é completamente diferente. Existem alguns tipos básicos (`number`, `date`, `string`, `boolean` e `array`, se bem me lembro) e o tipo `object`. Mas não são classes. Você tem, por assim dizer, objetos sem classe.

E aqui o pulo do gato: os tipos em Javascript são funções. Se você quiser criar um novo tipo, você declara uma função. Ela se torna construtora de si mesma, e todos os membros que você atribuir diretamente a ela são estáticos. Para dar membros de instância ao seu tipo, você os associa ao protótipo (*prototype*) da função.

Uma vez que todo tipo que você escrever por conta própria em Javascript será necessariamente uma função, dizemos que em Javascript, as funções são os objetos ([ou "cidadãos", de acordo com a definição](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen)) de primeira classse.

Comment: Não há nada de subjectivo nem de abstrato na afirmação. [Função de primeira classe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) é um conceito bem definido e conhecido, e nada tem a ver com programação orientada a objectos.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues eu não conhecia essa definição. Obrigado! Estou ajustando o texto.

Answer (score 1):

Em inglês *first-class functions*, porém não se pode confundir e pré-conceituar que existem funções de primeira, segunda, terceira classe, etc. Nem tão pouco são funções especiais, diferenciadas das outras.

Em JavaScript e em outras linguagens modernas as funções são de primeira classe, isto é, são objetos que possuem propriedades e métodos e podem ser passados como argumentos, serem atribuídos a variáveis ou retornados como qualquer outro objeto (http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)

Luciano Ramalho também fala muito bem [sobre o conceito](http://javascriptbrasil.com/2012/09/05/funcoes-de-primeira-classe).

Comment: E o qe não é de "primeira-classe" é o que? Quais são os exemplos?

Comment: É como o Luciano Ramalho comenta no texto dele. Todas as funções são de primeira classe, não existem funções de segunda classe (existem métodos, que também são objetos de primeira classe nessas linguagens).

Um termo relacionado é “funções de ordem superior” (higher order functions). Aí sim estamos falando de uma categoria especial de funções: são funções que recebem outras funções como argumentos, e/ou devolvem funções como resultado. Em JavaScript, vários métodos de Array como map, filter, forEach e reduce são exemplos de funções de ordem superior.