# Para que servem variaveis/funções anonimas e closures? E que são? Como usar?

Tags: javascript, closures, função-anônima

Acho que a maior parte da pergunta já foi feita no título.

Sendo mais específico, eu queria exemplos reais de utilização dessas técnicas e a relação entre elas.

Nota: li outras respostas relacionadas, mas não consegui entender 100%.

Comment: Essa pergunta é bastante ampla. Acho que seria melhor se você focasse a pergunta em um daqueles exemplos que você disse não ter entendido 100%

Comment: Já leste esta (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/129)  e esta (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9936/129)? Se ainda não está claro podes especificar que parte devemos reforçar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Funções anonimas e closures são elementos bem distintos, mas basicamente funções anonimas são funções que não tem nome (parece óbvio) e isto permite uma facilidade enorme na implementação de callbacks

O closures tem a ver com o alcance/escopo de uma variável, bem útil para resolver o envio de parâmetros para funções de eventos utilizando funções que retornam uma função.