# Qual a forma correta de declarar uma function javascript?

Tags: javascript, funções

Há algum tempo, venho observando a utilização de duas formas de declaração de `function` `javascript`, sendo as seguintes:

**- Forma 1:**

```
function soma1(val1, val2){
    return val1 + val2;
};
```

**- Forma 2:**

```
var soma2 = function(val1, val2){
    return val1 + val2;
};
```

As duas formas parecem funcionar igualmente.

Minhas duvidas são as seguintes:

1. Há alguma forma certa ou errada?
2. Há alguma forma considerada padrão?
3. Há diferenças entre as duas formas? (de: performance, contexto de execução, etc)
4. Há alguma recomendação de uso?

Comment: @bfavaretto, apesar de ser bastante esclarecedora, as respostas da outra questão (marcada como duplicada), elas não respondem completamente as duvidas desta (em minha opinião), já que está diferentemente da outra, questiona, se há forma correta, se há padrão, e quais as recomendações de uso, o que as respostas da outra questão respondem claramente desta é a diferença entre as duas formas de declarar `function`. Vou postar para reabrir e ver o que a comunidade considera.

Comment: Fernando, é porque são bem poucas diferenças: muda o momento em que a função está disponível dentro do escopo, e tem o fato da primeira forma exigir que a função seja nomeada. Só isso, o resto é questão de uso, não existe forma correta. Ainda acho duplicata, mesmo que as respostas lá precisem de algum complemento (vou tentar complementar a minha nos próximos dias).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe diferença entre elas e por isto não dá para dizer que há uma forma correta. Cada uma tem uma finalidade.

A preferência deve ser pela primeira forma, ela pode ser considerada a padrão. Esta é a declaração normal de função. E ela pode ser ligeiramente mais rápida dependendo da implementação do JavaScript. Mas eu já vi coisas óbvias e intuitivas funcionarem ao contrário.

A segunda forma não está criando uma função tradicional. Está criando o que se chama [função anônima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9936/101). Você associa o código escrito nela à uma variável e esta pode ser transferida para outras partes da aplicação provendo grande flexibilidade quando esta é exigida.

Nesta forma a função só existe logicamente (está em escopo) enquanto tiver uma variável sustendo ela.

Ela tem uma vantagem adicional que ela pode funcionar como uma [clausura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101). Ou seja, ela pode guardar um valor obtido através de uma variável que fora declarada no escopo da função que criou esta função anônima. Em outras palavras, ela prende este valor dentro da função anônima e pode usá-lo enquanto a ela estiver "viva".

Uma função anônima pode ser retornada da função criadora como resultado dela. Ela também pode ser passada como argumento para outra função que espera um código para executar. Outra utilização é como valor de um membro de um objeto. Raramente ela tem utilidade se não for passada para outros pontos da aplicação de alguma forma. A função normal também pode fazer isto mas se programar dentro dos padrões é mais raro ser útil fazer isto.

Nas perguntas *linkadas* existe mais informações sobre o funcionamento da segunda já que este não é o foco desta pergunta.

Exemplo de uso de função anônima:

```js
function criaFuncao() {
   return function() { console.log("oi"); };
}
var codigo = criaFuncao();
codigo(); // vai imprimir oi
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/InnerFunction.js).