# Function expression vs function declaration

Tags: javascript, funções

Qual a definição para **function expression** e **function declaration**? Quais as principais vantagens de uma em relação a outra?

Comment: Olhe se aqui pode te ajudar.
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp

Comment: Veja [esta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13364/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-as-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-var-name-function-e-function-name) se já não abrange sua pergunta.

Comment: @Fernando verdade... [eu bem que procurei mas não encontrei](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Function+expression+function+declaration), também achava que já tinha sido perguntada.

Comment: @Sergio, sim a pesquisa aqui no SO não é das melhores (deviam investir nisso), hehe, é que eu já fiz [está pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55204/qual-a-forma-correta-de-declarar-uma-function-javascript) duplicata [desta citada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13364/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-as-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-var-name-function-e-function-name).

Comment: Também procurei por aqui e não encontrei. Acredito que a partir de agora a resposta a essa dúvida será encontrada mais facilmente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elas são bem parecidas.
A diferênça principal é se estão disponíveis em todo o contexto de execução ou não.

Uma função declarada por *Function Expression* não vai estar acessível em linhas de código anteriores à linha de execução atual. Só está disponivel em *run-time*, no momento em que a linha for corrida pelo código.

Enquando que uma função declarada por *Function Declaration* está sempre disponível, chama-se a isto *Hoisting*, disponivel em *parse-time*, mesmo nas linhas anteriores.

Ambas respeitam regras de escopo.

#### Function Declaration

```
alert(foo());
function foo() { return 5; }
```

funciona pois a função está presente em todo o contexto de execução

#### Function Expression

```
alert(foo());
var foo = function() { return 5; }
```

Isto vai dar erro.
`foo();` só pode ser corrido depois da linha que onde a variável passa a ser uma função.

**Nota 1:**

curiosamente na *Function Expression* a variável já está iniciada/declarada (com valor *undefined*) mas o seu valor (de função) só será atribuído depois de o código passar por essa linha na execução. No exemplo de cima:

```
alert(foo());
var foo = function() { return 5; }
```

Vai dar erro. Nomeadamente:

> TypeError: foo is not a function

(nalguns browsers dá `undefined is not a function` em vêz do nome da variável)

mas repara que não dá este erro:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined

que seria o caso se `foo` ainda não estivesse declarada.

**Nota 2:**

Se usar-mos por exemplo a seguinte *Function Declaration* em modo `"use strict"` funções defenidas em partes condicionais do código vão dar erro. Ou seja não se pode usar. Exemplo:

```
"use strict";
if (bar) {
    function foo() { return 5; }; // dá erro!
}
```

**Nota 3:**

Na maioria dos casos não faz muita diferênça qual usar. Porém há casos onde a *Function Expression* é muito útil e faz algo que a *Function Declaration* não permite fazer.Exemplo:

```
var id = document.geElementById;
```

ou seja estamos a atribuir uma função a uma variável. Isto poupa espaço no código futuro e nõ seria possível via *Function Declaration*.