# Por que posso acessar funções normais antes da declaração, mas as funções anônimas não?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

Em Javascript, é possível utilizar/usar uma função antes da sua declaração.

```js
MyFunc();
function MyFunc() {
  return console.log('blah!');
}
```

Porém, quando se trata de funções anônimas e closures, não é possível fazer como o exemplo acima:

```js
var MyFunc;

MyFunc();

MyFunc = function () {
  return console.log('Nada de Blah!');
};
```

Apesar de saber que funciona assim, nunca soube o porquê.

Por que isso acontece?

Comment: Também dup: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63912/129

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme [respondi sobre PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/169753/101) a compilação é feita em dois passos. Ao contrário da função normal que é uma declaração, a função anônima faz parte do algoritmo e não é analisada no primeiro passo, por isso não pode ser considerada no primeiro passo, durante a análise das declarações. No segundo passo já está tarde, só será considerado os símbolos gerados no primeiro passo, ou o que pode ser interpretado até aquele ponto do código no segundo passo.

Mas tem um complicador. Por ser uma linguagem dinâmica e o valor da variável pode até mesmo deixar de ser uma função, não tem como ele garantir que terá a função ali, a verificação só pode ser feita no momento de sua execução. É um problema semelhante ao `include` relatado na pergunta do PHP.

Se a linguagem fosse tipada `MyVar` teria que ter a [assinatura da função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101), aí o código da pergunta funcionaria, não importa onde a "variável" fosse declarada. Note que estou falando [até da declaração, nem precisa ser a definição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101).