# Por que em PHP é possível acessar as funções antes da linha que elas foram declaradas?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem

Por que em PHP é possível chamar uma função antes da linha em que a mesma foi declarada?

```
echo ah(); // 'Ah!'

function ah() {
     return 'Ah!';
}
```

Observem que eu chamei `ah()` primeiro, depois declarei. Mesmo assim, ela foi executada. Mas a função teoricamente não existiria antes dessa linha?  Então como ela foi chamada?

Como isso acontece internamente? Eu pensava que o script fosse executado sequencialmente, porém ao chamar uma função que é declarada depois isso me dá um outro entendimento.

Isso parece funcionar apenas quando  a declaração é feita no mesmo script.

Já quando ocorre uma inclusão de script depois do chamamento da função, isso não acontece, mesmo que dentro do `include` exista a função chamada.

<sub>index.php</sub>

```
echo ah();

include 'ah.php';
```

<sub>a.php</sub>

```
function ah() { return 'Ah!'; }
```

Isso iria gerar:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ah() in index.php

Ou seja: posso chamar uma função antes da linha de declaração, desde que ela esteja no mesmo arquivo. Se for com `include`, isso não funciona.

Por quê?

- Qual é a diferença entre a função declarada depois do chamamento que está no mesmo script para a função que foi chamada antes da declaração proveniente de um `include`?
- No primeiro caso, o PHP analisa o código apenas uma vez para saber se a função foi declarada? Como essa "mágica" foi feita?

Primeiro exemplo no [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/qaNV8Q)

Comment: Eu posso estar enganado, mas o include no php é diferente de outras linguagens, na verdade é como se ele fosse um `eval` (na verdade ele é um `eval`) e o "escopo" muitas vezes é diferente, tanto que o `include` pode até retornar valores.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Não posso afirmar com autoridade sobre o funcionamento exato do PHP, mas conheço sobre [compiladores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101) ([um interpretador não deixa de ser um compilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77070/101)), e todos que eu conheço que permitem a função ser chamada antes de ser declarada faz o processo de *lexing* e *parsing* em dois passos.

Primeiro ele analisa todas declarações, criando uma tabela de símbolos públicos que poderão ser usados no *script*, e ignora o que está no corpo das funções. Depois ele analisa os algoritmos contidos nas funções, então quando a chamada ocorre, já há ciência da declaração. Simples assim.

A análise do primeiro passo não considera a inclusão de arquivos, por isso ele não resolve os símbolos contidos nesse novo arquivo. Nem poderia já que o `include` é resolvido dinamicamente (no momento da execução). Ele pode ser até mesmo condicional, então só após análise do algoritmo e da efetiva execução é que ele pode decidir se incluirá ou não, por isso não pode ser resolvido no primeiro passo. Nem mesmo no segundo, é resolvido na execução.

C e Pascal são algumas das poucas exceções que não fazem em dois passos. C++ faz em vários, e mesmo assim não permite a declaração fora de ordem. Poderia, mas talvez possa ficar confuso por causa do `include`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ah, faz um pouco mais de sentido agora. Eu pensava que ele "fazia o trabalho apenas uma vez".

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Melhorei.