# É possível usar funções em uma ordem arbitrária em C++?

Tags: c++, funções, característica-linguagem, compilação

Aparentemente, a ordem em que as funções são escritas importa em C++. Exemplo, este código compila:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int add_number(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
}

int main(){
    int a{10};
    int b{43};
    cout<<add_number(a,b) <<endl;
}
```

Mas este código não compila:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a{10};
    int b{43};
    cout<<add_number(a,b) <<endl;
}

int add_number(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
}
```

Eu achei isso inesperado porque em Rust, a outra linguagem compilada que conheço, a ordem em que as funções é escrita não importa. Exemplo:

```rust
fn add_numbers(x:i32, y:i32)->i32{
    return x+y
}

fn main() {
    let a:i32 =10;
    let b:i32 =43;
    println!("{}",add_numbers(a,b))
}
```

Se inverter a ordem das funções, o resultado não se altera.

É possível fazer o mesmo em C++? Em outras palavras, é possível acessar funções independente da ordem em que elas foram escritas?

O que explica essa diferença de comportamento entre C++ e Rust?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C e C++ são linguagens que optaram por serem de **um passo**, ou seja, elas vão analisando o que encontram na ordem e vão avaliando o que fazer com aquilo na ordem que que veio.

Linguagens modernas tendem a evitar essa limitação, ainda que a performance de compilação sofra um pouco.

No passado esse ganho era muito importante hoje não é mais. Mas é possível que alguns códigos se valha dessa característica e uma mudança poderia quebrar a compatibilidade de C e C++.

As linguagens mais modernas funcionam com a compilação em dois passos (não confundir com fases). Então há uma leitura e "interpretação" de alguns pontos do código e só depois outros pontos são avaliados. Em geral o que é de mais alto nível tais como a declaração de tipos, estruturas e informações globais, como são as funções, é que são avaliadas no primeiro passo, então o compilador tem uma tabela de símbolos e informações adicionais de como eles são compostos para usar no segundo passo. Desta forma a ordem como cada coisa foi [declarada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101) não importa. Isso dá mais flexibilidade cobrando o preço da performance.

[Falei disso sobre PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/169749/101).

Note que o compilador só precisa saber a [assinatura da função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) para ver se seu código está a chamando em conformidade com o que foi declarado, só é preciso verificar o contrato, não precisa da função definida antes porque isso é detalhes de implementação, inclusive o código da função poderia nem estar nesse arquivo ou mesmo unidade de compilação, poderia vir de um [biblioteca estática ou dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/149372/101), como é em outras linguagens.

As linguagens mais modernas costumam ter arquivos com metadados com as assinaturas quando o fonte não está disponível (ou eles leem os fontes por inteiro, caso típico das linguagens interpretadas, o que é muito pior).

Em C e C++ você precisa dos fontes pelo menos das assinaturas de funções e as estruturas e outras informações globais que podem ser disponibilizadas externamente. Novamente a modernidade trouxe algo que essas linguagens não podiam ter na época. Isso é resolvido com os chamados [*headers*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154070/101).

C++ poderia ter mudado isso mas perderia alguma compatibilidade com C. Mas agora eles não se preocupam tanto assim e acharam um meio de ter alguma modernidade sem quebrar a compatibilidade.

Pode-se trabalhar com [módulos em C++20](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-160) para frente. Eles são implementados da mesma forma moderna que Rust e outras linguagens usam e as declarações não precisa estar presentes antes do uso, desde que elas existam e estejam presentes em um módulo, que é algo novo na linguagem, e claro, que ele tenha sido importado. Módulos são bem mais que isto. [Documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules). [Proposta](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3347.pdf). [Apresentação](https://meetingcpp.com/mcpp/slides/2019/modules-the-beginners-guide-meetingcpp2019.pdf).

Quando estava pesquisando achei [Por que, em C, uma função precisa ser declarada antes de ser usada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/366060/101), talvez uma duplicata, exceto pelo último parágrafo que eu respondi aqui.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Na verdade isso é mais uma característica da linguagem.

Em C++ (assim como em C), você deve ter a função declarada antes de utilizá-la. Note, no seu primeiro exemplo, que a função `add_number` foi declarada (e implementada) *antes* de ser chamada. Portanto, não há erros.

Já no segundo exemplo, a função `add_number`, ao ser invocada em `main`, ainda não havia sido declarada e nem implementada.

Conforme apontou a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/507701/69296), é possível ainda declarar uma função e, depois, implementá-la. Isso acontece, por exemplo, nos [*header files*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/333902/7445826), que são incluídos no começo do arquivo. Aliás, é por isso também que esse tipo de inclusão vem no início do arquivo, isto é, para assegurar que todas as funções externas estejam propriamente declaradas antes do uso.

Portanto, a resposta para a pergunta é não. Você não pode utilizar uma função em ordem arbitrária, de modo que a declaração é obrigatória antes do uso.

---

Esse tipo de "preocupação" não é necessária em Rust. Isso porque o compilador do Rust analisa todas as declarações de um arquivo antes de verificar o corpo das funções, de modo que a ordem de declaração torna-se irrelevante.

Answer (score 2):

Em `C` só é possível usar um membro que já foi declarado, seria um erro similar a fazer isso:

```
x = 10;
int x;
```

Por isso, o compilador ao encontrar um membro (variável, function, structure, etc) valida se já foi declarado, então se for usado no `main`, deve ser declarado antes.

De qualquer forma, assim como as variáveis, é possível declarar as funções, e implementá-las a seguir, então o código funcionará se for assim por exemplo:

```
// aqui só declarou a function, indicando ao compilador que existe
int add_number(int x, int y);

int main(){
    int a{10};
    int b{43};
    cout<<add_number(a,b) <<endl;
}


// aqui implementou. A implementação pode ficar no final, pq só será utilizada em runtime
int add_number(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
}
```