# Como utilizar um CSS pela url do site?

Tags: javascript, java, css, ajax

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu utilizar um CSS diferente para um sistema web "Java" sem ter que incluir no código fonte?

Tenho um arquivo novo CSS que eu redimensionei os botões e espaços e preciso utilizar ele nesta aplicação web, preciso apontar o sistema para esse novo CSS sem ter que mexer no código fonte.

Um amigo me disse que tem como passar isso pela URL, mas não sei como fazer...

Exemplo dado por ele http://endereco_do_meu_sistema/?e_o_CSS

Lembrando que o sistema já tem seus CSS no código.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Quando você diz **sem mexer no código fonte** você está se referindo aos HTMLs ou a parte do backend?

Comment: Cara, deixa eu ver se compreendi, tu pode mexer no HTML? ou tu quer realmente passar pelo link de acesso a tua página o css?

Comment: Eu não poderei mexer no HTML, teria que fazer algo como passar esse CSS pela URL. O Site seria chamado pela url e quando ele subir ele teria que ler esse css e mudar os botões e espaços que estão informados nesse novo css...

Comment: Isso que você está querendo fazer é impossivel, se você não tem acesso ao código fonte não importa por onde você tente passar o css ele não irá interpretar, uma vez que você não pode editar o sistema para buscar e aplicar o parametro que você passou

Comment: E se eu colocar o site em um Iframe eu poderia mudar???

Comment: **Não tem como fazer isso**, você poderia criar um código javascript para importar o arquivo e executa-lo no console do navegador assim que entrasse no site, mas teria que fazer isso **todas as vezes** que acessasse o site.

Comment: @LuizCarlosCarvalho você não pode alterar o conteúdo de um iframe por css nem por javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Resposta

Impossível fazer isso.

#### Porque?

Parâmetros na URL são enviados para o servidor, onde está o seu código fonte, então no seu código você decidirá o que fazer com o parâmetro.

Se você não pode mexer no código fonte, então você está falando qual é o CSS, mas o código não está "nem ai", pois ele não sabe o que fazer com essa informação.

Então você precisa de alguma programação que importe esse arquivo CSS no teu código, isso é feito geralmente no lado servidor, exemplo:

```
//Endereço: http://endereco_do_meu_sistema/?css=meucss.css

$css = empty($_GET['css']) ? null : $_GET['css'];
// "Importa" o arquivo meucss.css
if (!is_null($css))
   echo "<link href=\"$css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\">";
```

<sub>O exemplo anterior foi escrito em PHP.</sub>

#### Alternativa

Uma alternativa é importar o arquivo via Javascript, por exemplo:

```
(function(css){
    var el = document.createElement('link');
    el.setAttribute('href', css);
    el.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    el.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    document.body.appendChild(el);
})('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css')
```

**Para a modificação ser realizada você deve executar essa função todas as vezes que acessar o site** (como não tens acesso ao código, pode fazer isso pelo console do navegador se disponível), ou seja a cada recarregamento de página o código deverá ser executado novamente, pois **essas modificações só são feitas no lado cliente e não são salvas** do lado do servidor.

---

#### Atenção: Essa resposta é exclusivamente para fins educacionais. NENHUM exemplo aqui deve ser utilizado em produção.

Comment: Como chamo essa Function que vc criou em javascript?

Comment: Opa @LuizCarlosCarvalho, ela já está se chamando sozinha, ela é uma [função anonima (leia +)](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9936/como-funcionam-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-an%C3%B4nimas). Caso queira nomea-la basta copiar o que está dentro do primeiro parenteses e adicionar um nome `function GetCSS(css){/... etc .../}` e chama-la `GetCSS('http://site/caminho/do/arquivo.css')`

Comment: @LuizCarlosCarvalho, se a resposta te serviu marque ela como aceita clicando no botão do lado esquerdo abaixo do número de votos. ;)

Comment: KaduAmaral - Muito obrigado pela resposta, funcionou perfeitamente... Mas no console do navegador e quando vai trocando de pagina tenho que ficar colocando o código, como faço para chamar a URL com essa função e como faria para ela ficar para todos as paginas. Não será possível o usuário usar console, pois o sistema é utilizado em coletores de dados. Desde já obrigado!

Comment: @LuizCarlosCarvalho como eu mencionei na resposta não tem como fazer isso, e também esse **método NÃO deve ser utilizado em produção de maneira alguma**. Mas poderias fazer um aplicativo para o navegador que fizesse isso, mas esse assunto não cabe aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Para importar um arquivo CSS em uma página basta fazer o link dentro do bloco **HEAD** do página que você deseja utilizar, exemplo:

```
<link href="CAMINHO_DO_ARQUIVO_CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Porém, obviamente, esse arquivo css deve estar dentro do diretório de seu site ou em algum link público que você tenha acesso.

Comment: Pelo que entendi: "_preciso apontar o sistema para esse novo CSS **sem ter que mexer no código fonte**._"

Comment: @Earendul quando ele falou sobre não mexer no código fonte automaticamente pensei em backend. Se não for isso eu excluo essa minha resposta

Comment: Isso não vai funcionar, pois não tenho acesso ao código *Html*... Teria que ser algo diferente pela *URL* mesmo. Tentei fazer via *Iframe* mas também não funcionou...

Comment: Isso ai... não tenho acesso ao código HTML... precisava passar o CSS pela URL!!!