# Entender contexto declaração determinada function javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho essa determinada declaração de função:

```
datasetCSR = this.execECM(function () {
    var co = this.DatasetFactory.createConstraint("ibv", instance, instance, this.ConstraintType.MUST);
    return this.DatasetFactory.getDataset("csr", null, [co], null);
});
```

**execECM** é uma função.

Gostaria de saber a teoria e contexto desse tipo de declaração de função.

Quando datasetCSR for executada ela automaticamente executa exeECM?

Comment: É isto que quer saber? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9936/101

Comment: Não tenho bem a certeza do que pedes na pergunta. Ora `this.execECM` é uma função. O que queres saber? acerca de `this.execECM` ou da função que lhe é passada como argumento? Podes explicar melhor a tua dúvida?

Comment: Eu gostaria de entender a lógica desse modo de criação de função.
execECM é uma função sim. O que eu não entendo é o que está ocorrendo. datasetCSR é função que quando executada ela chama a função exeECM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datasetCSR` é uma variável que quando declarada executa e recebe o valor de retorno do método `execECM`.

Considerando a definição do objeto como:

```
var obj = {
  execECM: function ( callback ) 
  {
    // será passado como argumento para esse método
    // uma função como callback 
    // você poderá invocá-la a qualquer momento dentro do contexto
    // de execECM
    return callback() + 5;
  },
  myCustomFunction: function ( value ) 
  {
    // declarando datasetCSR e associando seu valor ao valor de retorno
    // do método execECM
    var
      datasetCSR = this.execECM( function () {
        return value;
      } );
    console.log( datasetCSR );
  }
};
```

O método `execECM` recebe uma função como *callback* para utilizar em algum momento no escopo de sua declaração.

> A callback function, also known as a higher-order function, is a function that is passed to another function (let’s call this other function “otherFunction”) as a parameter, and the callback function is called (or executed) inside the otherFunction.

[Understand JavaScript Callback Functions and Use Them](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/)

Usando o objeto declarado anteriormente, teremos:

```
obj.myCustomFunction( 10 ); // 15
obj.myCustomFunction( 1 ); // 6
obj.execECM( 10 ) // Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function(…)
var calls = function () 
{
  return 100;
};
obj.execECM( calls ); // 105
```