# Qual a função desse 'e' que é passado como parâmetro?

Tags: javascript, jquery, funções, parâmetros

O exemplo que vou mostrar aqui é só para ilustrar.

Gostaria de entender de fato como funciona esse `e` que geralmente é passado como parâmetro em várias funções que encontros em códigos por aí.

```
 $(".fotos").each(function(e){
                    if(e <= e + 2){
                        teste[posicao][e] = e;

                        if((e+1)%3 == 0){
                            posicao +=1;
                            teste[posicao] = new Array();
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: O `e` era normalmente usado para eventos, ou `event`. Mas generalizou e todos começaram a usar `e`, sem de fato entender o porque. Mas não necessariamente precisa chamar `e`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quando usas a API do jQuery para [`$(".fotos").each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) esse método aceita uma função como argumento. Essa função é também chamada *iterador*, ou seja a função que será chamada e corrida para cada um dos `$(".fotos")` encontrados por esse seletor.

A variável no teu exemplo chama-se `e` mas podia ser outro nome. O importante é o que ela contém. E no caso do jQuery é o `index` (indície/posição) desse elemento que está a ser iterado no array, tipo: *Number*.

Se essa função tivesses dois argumentos o segundo seria o próprio valor, e será o tipo do que estiver dentro da array e a ser iterado, um elemento com classe `.foto` no teu exemplo.

Nota que o jQuery faz ao contrário da API nativa de JavaScript, que disponibiliza nesse *iterador* primeiro o valor, e depois o indice.

### Mas o `(e)` é só isso em todos os casos de funções aí pela web?

Bom, não dá para generalizar assim. Porém a variável `e` é usada muitas vezes como abreviatura para "elemento" ou até "evento".

No teu exemplo, nem devia ser `e`, semanticamente, mas sim `i`. Se houvesse dois argumentos eu escreveria `.each(function(i, e){` como abreviaturas de `.each(function(index, elemento){`.

Se fosse outro tipo de função, como uma callback de um oscultador de eventos, o `e` seria abreviatura de evento. Por exemplo:

```
$('div.teste').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // aqui "e" é abreviatura de evento e contem o objeto evento
```

Comment: +1, e o ponto a respeito de `i` é bem válido; um parâmetro i é prática comum para índices.

Answer (score 5):

Isto [**é** um parâmetro. Um argumento será passado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) para ele. Imagino que mesmo não sabendo a terminologia correta, saiba para que serve um parâmetro.

Neste caso o `e` irá receber argumentos enviados pela função `each()`. Esta função tem por objetivo varrer uma coleção de dados. Então cada membro desta coleção provocará uma chamada à [função anônima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9936/101) escrita ali e o elemento da coleção (neste caso, o índice dele) será enviado como argumento.

Na verdade estou descrevendo o que eu sei desta função. Funções que chamam funções anônimas devem documentar bem como a função anônima (que você escreveu) deve ser escrita, que parâmetros ela deve receber, em linhas gerais o que ela deve fazer e o que deve retornar.

E obviamente que você pode escrever uma função sua que receba como argumento uma função anônima. Se fizer isto, tem que documentar como ela será usada.

Vamos ver o fonte da função `each()`:

```
function (obj, callback) {
    var length, i = 0;
    if (isArrayLike(obj)) {
        length = obj.length;
        for (; i < length; i++) if (callback.call(obj[i], i, obj[i]) === false) break;
    } else for (i in obj) if (callback.call(obj[i], i, obj[i]) === false) break;
    return obj;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/CallbackParameter.js).

O [`callback.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) é que faz a chamada à sua função. Os parâmetros desta função são:

- `thisArg` - que é o elemento
- `arg1` e `arg2` - que é o índice e novamente o elemento

O `arg1` é que realmente será passado como argumento para a sua função anônima. No caso ele é expressado pela variável `i` no laço.

Se a sua função declarar os parâmetros como `(i, e)` você poderá receber o índice e o elemento sendo analisado naquela iteração. Em algumas situações basta receber o índice, em outras também precisa conhecer o elemento exato.

Um adendo final: quase sempre um *loop* comum resolve tão bem ou melhor que o uso da função `each()`.

Answer (score 4):

Vamos desmontar a chamada de função:

```
$(".fotos").each(function(e) {
```

- **`$(".fotos")`** é um *seletor* do jQuery. O alvo pode ser um membro apenas, ou uma coleção;
- **`.each`** é um método que permite uma chamada de função para todos os membros da coleção retornados pelo seletor;
- **`function(e)`** é a função chamada pelo método ***each***. O parâmetro ***e***, neste caso, referencia o índice do elemento selecionado.

Portanto, se o seu seletor retornar uma coleção contento 3 elementos, a função será chamada 3 vezes, sendo o valor de ***e*** o valor do índice.

O nome ***e*** é arbitrário. Poderia ser qualquer nome válido, contanto que o código que o consome fizesse a referência correta:

```
$(".fotos").each(function(parm1){
            if(parm1 <= parm1 + 2){
                teste[posicao][parm1] = parm1;
```

Comment: Mal posso ver seus movimentos :P

Comment: @JéfersonBueno não contavam com minha astúcia.

Comment: O que eu queria entender, é o que exatamente é atribuido ao "e".
Nesse caso um número inteiro já que há uma comparação? Mas como um número inteiro? De onde ele veio? O exemplo foi só ilustrativo, como eu disse...

Comment: @Sergio você está completamente correto. Eu estava com o .forEach do angular em mente. Muito Obrigado pela correção.

Comment: @ErickLemos exatamente. Neste caso, `e` recebe um valor inteiro, gerado pelo método `.each`.