# Qual a diferença entre esses usos da função setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, funções, função-anônima, settimeout

Qual a diferença entre usar o `setTimeout()` assim

```
setTimeout(()=>this.logicaRotacao(), 3000)
```

e assim?

```
setTimeout(this.logicaRotacao(), 3000)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O primeiro passa uma [função anônima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9936/101) que chama `this.logicaRotacao()`, então no momento adequado (a cada 3 segundos nestes exemplo) ela será chamada pelo *engine* do JS, já que você *setou* esta ação através da função `setTimeout()`. Isto é um mecanismo de [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/101). veja a [notação de fecha ou seta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114367/101). E ainda [mais detalhes e exemplo de uso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88986/101). E outra [pergunta canônica sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/101).

O segundo executa a função `this.logicaRotacao()` e passa seu resultado para a função `setTimeout()` executar a cada 3 segundos. Se o que for retornado por `this.logicaRotacao()` não for uma função dará um erro ou resultado inesperado.

Isto poderia ser correto também:

```
setTimeout(this.logicaRotacao, 3000)
```

Neste caso você não está chamando a função e sim passando esta função. Sem os parênteses não é uma chamada, e sim pegar apenas o endereço da função. É até mais correto que a primeira opção neste exemplo porque o seu código tem uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) extra sem necessidade, está passando uma função que chama uma função sem fazer nada mais, então passa função que vai chamar logo.

A [documentação da função](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) indica bem que ela espera uma função. Há uma diferença enorme entre passar uma função e chamar uma função. Leia o *link* acima para entender melhor este retardo na execução da função.

Perceba abaixo o tempo para mostrar cada um. O primeiro demora o tempo colocado, o segundo faz imediatamente.

```js
function logicaRotacao() {
    console.log("ok");
}
setTimeout(()=>this.logicaRotacao(), 5000);
```

```js
function logicaRotacao() {
    console.log("ok");
}
setTimeout(logicaRotacao(), 5000);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/SetTimeout.js).

Answer (score 6):

O primeiro argumento de setTimeout é uma função de callback.

Em `setTimeout(()=>this.logicaRotacao(), 3000)` você está definindo uma função usando a notação `arrow function`, essa função quando invocada executa `this.logicaRotacao()`

Em `setTimeout(this.logicaRotacao(), 3000)` você está executando a função `this.logicaRotacao` e passando o retorno dela para `setTimeout`. A menos que o retorno de `this.logicaRotacao` seja uma função, isso não irá funcionar, você tem que passar a função em si, não o retorno dela. O certo seria `setTimeout(this.logicaRotacao, 3000)`