# Qual a utilização dos dois pontos em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Qual é o uso dos dois pontos `:` em JavaScript, como o exemplo abaixo:

```
function paciente(nome, idade, altura) {
  var clazz = {
    imprime: function() {
      alert("nome: " + nome + ", idade: " + idade);
    }
  return clazz;
}
```

Sei que `imprime` irá receber uma funções anônima, mas ele irá ser um objeto? Variável? E porque o uso dos dois pontos? E quando devo utilizar?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bem, a utilização dos dois pontos é basicamente empregada em objetos:

```
var frutas = {
  "banana":{
    cor: "yellow"
  }
}
```

Com o objeto você simplesmente "navega" entre os níveis das chaves:

```
frutas.banana.cor; // yellow
```

Assim sempre que se usa uma chave em  um objeto, se atribui um valor a ela, por meio dos dois ponto `:`, ao invés do igual `=`, usado para váriaveis, em geral.

No seu exemplo creio que esteja faltando uma chave `}`, mas deve ter sido a colagem...

```
function paciente(nome, idade, altura) {
  var clazz = {
    imprime: function() {
      alert("nome: " + nome + ", idade: " + idade);
    }
  }
  return clazz;
}
```

Você possui uma função, que possui um objeto, esse objeto recebe uma chave `imprime`, este recebe uma função que retorna uma concatenação dos dois primeiros argumentos da função, ou seja:

```
paciente('João', 35, "1,80m").imprime() // João, 35
```

Existem outras utilizações, por exemplo em variáveis condicionais:

```
var cor = arguments.length > 0 ? arguments[0] : "black";
```

No exemplo acima, saindo do pressuposto que este código esteja dentro de uma função, você está dizendo: *se o número de argumentos for maior que zero a variável "cor" vai ser igual ao primeiro argumento, senão será igual a "black"*.

O "senão"/"else" é representado pelo *colon* (dois pontos).

Há ainda os [`labels`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), implementado com o EcmaScript, olhe:

```
var i, j;

loop1:
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      // Primeira declaração rotulada "loop1"
   loop2:
   for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {   // Segunda declaração rotulada "loop2"
      if (i === 1 && j === 1) {
         continue loop1;
      }
      console.log("i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
   }
}
```

Você pode usar um `label` para identificar um *loop*, e depois usar o [*break*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) ou [*continue*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) para indicar se um programa deve interromper o *loop* ou prosseguir com a sua execução.

Deixei essa última opção apenas para nível de curiosidade já quase nunca vejo assuntos sobre esses `labels`, também não uso com muita frequências, mas são bem interessantes, recomendo que veja os links.

Comment: Obrigado @Samir Braga

Answer (score 8):

Quando crias um objeto em JavaScript podes fazer de maneiras diferentes. Um objeto consiste em grupos/pares, de chaves e valores. Para criar um objeto podes usar essa notação com o `:` que não é mais que o separador entre a chave e o objeto.

Quando usas `window.foo = bar;` estás a adicionar uma propriedade nova ao objeto `window` com o valor da variável `bar`. Também podes fazer isso dinamicamente, com a notação de parenteses retos:

```
var x = 'foo';
window[x] = bar;
```

este exemplo na prática vai dar ao mesmo que o primeiro exemplo.

Porém para criar um objeto já com um par chave/valor, ou um objeto com muitos pares tens de usar a notação/sintaxe `chave:valor`, ou seja um Objeto literal:

```
var objeto = {
    foo: 'Olá',
    bar: 'Mundo'
};

alert(objeto.foo + ' ' + objeto.bar);
```

Answer (score 6):

Neste contexto específico ele é o separador entre o nome de um membro e seu valor, na [inicialização de um objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). É usado em [*object literals*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals).

Então neste caso o `imprime` é o nome do membro, em outras linguagens ele poderia ser considerado como a variável de instância de uma classe. No JS ele é um membro do protótipo, que no fundo é um [mapa de dados, uma tabela *hash*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array).

O [valor guardado nele é uma função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9936/101) ([entenda a diferença para uma função normal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/101)). Sim, em JS uma função pode ser guardada em uma variável para ser chamada posteriormente através da variável.

Uma outra forma de escrever o mesmo de forma menos conveniente seria assim, só para efeitos de entendimento (não é uma substituição pura e simples):

```
clazz.imprime = function() {
    alert("nome: " + nome + ", idade: " + idade);
}
```

Ou assim:

```
clazz["imprime"] = function() {
    alert("nome: " + nome + ", idade: " + idade);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/AtribToMember.js).