# O que significa o operador "=>"?

Tags: javascript, expressões-lambda, operadores, ecmascript-6

Eu estava vendo algumas soluções em JavaScript e em um caso eu vi esta linha de comando: `return args.reduce((s, v) => s + v, 0);`. Porém não sei o que significa o operador `=>`.

Qual a função dele?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

É conhecido como  **Arrow functions**.
Uma [Arrow function](http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/es6/arrow-functions/) é exatamente como uma função/callback normal, só que menos verbosa e referências de instâncias como `this` são tomadas dos "arredores" (o que evita `.bind()` ou aqueles `var that=this`).

Então:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3];
squares = numbers.map(x => x * x);
```

que é equivalente a:

```
squares = numbers.map(function (x) { return x * x });
```

Eu não quero escrever uma extensa resposta com todos os detalhes porque isso é redundante. Há tanto sobre isso lá fora que não vale o esforço. Como exemplo, aqui há um EXCELENTE conteúdo sobre isso:

http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html

Comment: Boa resposta mas, sobre o seu comentário no final, acho que mesmo tendo muito conteúdo disponível em outros lugares, sempre vale a pena adicionar o máximo possível de detalhes e informações na sua resposta. Principalmente se a maior parte do conteúdo externo está em inglês.

Comment: @Gabe Eu discordo. Isso é mais válido para assuntos pouco abordados e com escasso conteúdo. Aqui no SOpt há uma cultura muito estranha de ser redundante demais e escrever respostas tão longas e enfadonhas quando tudo que é preciso é apenas uma resposta direta. É exatamente o caso aqui: Há excessivo conteúdo sobre o assunto lá fora.

Comment: @felipsmartins concordo em partes, mas o que o Gabe disse não foi pra escrever uma "resposta longa" e sim talvez pra colocar no inicio mais direto e separar um sub-topico para outros detalhes que podem vir a ser interessantes, ninguém disse que é obrigatório, isso é apenas uma dica, visto que o link esta em inglês. Entenda como uma critica construtiva e não uma obrigatoriedade, a resposta já esta ótima do jeito que esta +1.

Answer (score 11):

Isto é uma função *lambda*, ou como costuma ser chamada, [função flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). É uma [função anônima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9936/101) com uma sintaxe mais simples. disponível desde EcmaScript 6.

Os parênteses à esquerda são os parâmetros e o que está à direita é o corpo da função que já é a expressão que gera o resultado que será retornado na função.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).