# sintaxe de erro ao usar then((result) =>

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Tenho um site que usa o pagar.me (getaway de pagamento) criei uma webview que roda perfeitamente nas versões android 7 e 8, mas nas versões 6, 5 e 4 a webview apresenta erro no javascript devido a sintaxe "then((result) =>" ou mais especifico "=>" como no código abaixo, existe alguma outra opção?

Mensagem do Android Studio: I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(244)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>", source: http://........

```
pagarme.client.connect({ encryption_key: 'ek_test_eee777dddsss5555' })
  .then(client => client.security.encrypt(card))
  .then(card_hash => {
```

Comment: `.then(function(client) { return client.security.encrypt(card) })`

Answer (score -2):

O sinal `=>` é uma notação diferente para criação de funções, chamada de *arrow function*. Para este caso em específico, apenas substitua o código de forma em fazer as funções da forma tradicional, ou seja:

Isso:

```
parametro => {...} // arrow function
```

Vire isso:

```
function(parametro) { return ...} // função tradicional
```

Lembrando o seguinte: as funções em forma de seta não necessitam do *return*, já as funções tradicionais necessitam, então vai ter que adicionar este também.

Obs.: Existem considerações sobre a diferença entre as funções de seta e as funções tradicionais, mas não possuo conhecimento suficiente para listar todas, por isso deixo abaixo o link quanto a discussão sobre essas diferenças. Para seu problema em questão a solução proposta é válida.

[O que significa o operador "=>"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114367/5878)

Comment: Embora a solução seja, de fato, trocar a *arrow function* pela *function*, acredito que você tenha escolhido as palavras erradas. A *arrow function* não é exatamente apenas uma *sugar syntax* para funções, existem considerações a serem feitas principalmente ao objeto `this`, como [discutido nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114367/5878).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Entendo. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento, e peço desculpas pela falta de conhecimento. Quis dar uma resposta completa sem ter conhecimento total sobre o assunto.

Comment: Neste caso em específico, os códigos poderiam ser considerados "equivalentes" e a relação seria direta (visto que não é utilizado o `this` dentro da função), então a resposta não está completamente errada; só recomendaria editar e corrigir os termos :D

Comment: Editei, espero que esteja melhor. Novamente desculpe a inexperiência, ainda estou aprendendo, tanto na programação como no SO.

Comment: Não há porque se desculpar, todos estamos aqui para aprender.