# Qual a diferença de fazer forEach(funcao) e forEach(funcao())? Por que a primeira funciona e a segunda não?

Tags: javascript

> error: undefined is not a function

```
const heros = ['visage', 'enchant', 'lone']
const nome = 'reubber'

function dotinha(nome) {

    return console.log(`'heroi é: ${nome}`)

}
/*heros.forEach(dotinha)   <---ASSIM FUNCIONA */
heros.forEach(dotinha())
```

bem, estou aprendendo os fundamentos de js ainda e queria entender mais o do pq qndo chamo a função dotinha com parênteses da error e qndo emito elas, a função funciona normalmente.

qual a diferença entre usar parenteses ou não e qndo devo utiliza-las?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Primeiro, vamos simplificar a função para você entender melhor, sem alterar seu comportamento.

A função nativa `console.log` exibe uma mensagem de log no console do navegador e nunca retornará algum valor. Isso implica que quando você associa o valor retornado a uma variável ela ficará `undefined`. Veja:

```js
const retorno = console.log("Mensagem de log");

console.log("Retorno", retorno);
```

Assim, a sua função na verdade é:

```js
function dotinha(nome) {
    console.log(`'heroi é: ${nome}`);
    return undefined;
}
```

Ou seja, o retorno da sua função **sempre** será `undefined`.

Agora, analisando o comportamento do `forEach`. Se você ler a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) verá que o primeiro parâmetro que o `forEach` espera é o `callback`, que é descrito como "função para executar em cada elemento, recebendo três argumentos". Ou seja, a função `forEach` espera receber como parâmetro uma função.

Quando você faz `heros.forEach(dotinha)` você está passando uma função, portanto funcionará. Porém, quando você faz `heros.forEach(dotinha())` você está passando o **retorno da função** como parâmetro, pois os parenteses aí indicarão que você quer chamá-la. Como a sua função sempre retorna `undefined` você está, na verdade, passando `undefined` como parâmetro do `forEach`, por isso o erro citado.

> error: undefined is not a function

Inclusive, perceba que quando você faz isso aparece a mensagem `'heroi é: undefined` antes de dar o erro, pois como você fez a chamada sem identificar o parâmetro, `dotinha()`, o valor de `nome` na função também será `undefined`.

```js
const heros = ['visage', 'enchant', 'lone']
function dotinha(nome) {

    return console.log(`'heroi é: ${nome}`)

}

heros.forEach(dotinha())
```

Se a ideia é apenas exibir a mensagem para cada herói, você não precisa de `return` na função. Na verdade, quando utilizada em conjunto com o `forEach` nunca fará sentido ter o `return`, pois o `forEach` ignora o retorno.

Também é possível utilizar funções anônimas:

```js
const heros = ['visage', 'enchant', 'lone']

heros.forEach(function (nome) {
  console.log(`Herói é: ${nome}`)
});
```

Ou utilizar as *arrow functions*:

```js
const heros = ['visage', 'enchant', 'lone']

heros.forEach(nome => {
  console.log(`Herói é: ${nome}`)
});
```

Ou ainda utilizar o `for` do JavaScript:

```js
const heros = ['visage', 'enchant', 'lone']

for (let nome of heros) {
  console.log(`Herói é: ${nome}`)
}
```

Como lição de casa:

- [Qual a diferença do For, ForEach e o Find no JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271587/5878)
- [Como funcionam funções anônimas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9936/5878)
- [O que significa o operador "=>"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114367/5878)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta anderson, ajudou dms!!

Comment: @Reubber Adicionei mais alguns detalhes, se lhe interessar.

Answer (score 4):

Existe a possibilidade de se usar `heroes.forEach(dotinha())` e ser sim algo útil! Só que, para isso, é necessário que a função `dotinha` retorne uma função. Abaixo um exemplo de brincadeira:

```js
const heros = ['visage', 'enchant', 'lone']
function dotinha() {
    return (nome) => console.log(`'heroi é: ${nome}`)
}

heros.forEach(dotinha())
```

Quando se trabalha com programação funcional, pode fazer sentido que uma função *retorne* outra função. De repente a função poderia ser outra, guardando, por exemplo, a contagem de heróis:

```js
const heroes1 = ['visage', 'enchant', 'lone']
const heroes2 = ['leon', 'claire', 'ada']

function dotinha() {
    let i = 0;

    return (nome) => { i++; console.log(`${i}-ésimo heroi do grupo é: ${nome}`); };
}

heroes1.forEach(dotinha())
heroes2.forEach(dotinha())
```