# Como seria sem ser em arrow function?

Tags: javascript

Como seria isso sem ser em arrow function?

```
document.querySelector('.menu .backdrop').addEventListener('click', e => {

    document.querySelector('header .menu').classList.remove('open');

});
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [O que significa o operador "=>"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114367/o-que-significa-o-operador)

Answer (score 3):

Seria usando uma função normal:

```
document.querySelector('.menu .backdrop').addEventListener('click', function (e) {

    document.querySelector('header .menu').classList.remove('open');

});
```

Comment: O "e" ta fazendo oq nessa função?

Comment: É o objeto do evento que o JS passará

Answer (score 1):

Substitua o `e =>` por `function(e)` :

```js
document.querySelector('.menu .backdrop').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  document.querySelector('header .menu').classList.remove('open');
});
```

```css
.open {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="backdrop">
    Clique
  </div>
</div>

<header>
  <div class="menu open">
    Vai sumir...
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: O "e" ta fazendo oq nessa função?

Comment: É o evento do JS, em ambos os exemplos, você vai receber o ```e``` como parâmetro, que será um objeto do evento clique.