# O que é o parâmetro passado em sort()

Tags: javascript, array, funções, classificação, parâmetros

Fazendo um exercícios me deparei com a seguinte passagem de parâmetro em `sort()`:

```
let notas = [7,6,10]

notas.sort((a,b) => a < b ? 1 : -1)

console.log(notas)
```

Não consegui entender, visto que tenho três valores na *array* e no parâmetro está sendo comparado dois, e também o que significa "1" e "-1".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O método `sort()` irá classificar uma coleção de dados através de um critério que definirá a ordem que se estabelecerá no objeto e ele precisa determinar se um dado é maior ou menor. Não importa como se chegará em qual é maior, pode ser algo simples ou pode ser algo complexo. Se passar nada para esse método há um critério padrão adotado que é analisar se um objeto é maior que outro da formas básica do tipo do dado.

Se desejar um critério diferente tem que passar uma função com um código que definite o critério. Tem várias formas de fazer isso, mas hoje o mais recomendado e simples pra maioria dos casos é usar a tal da [*arrow function*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114367/101).

Essa técnica é chamada [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/101).

O método `sort()` chamará essa função em cada passo da ordenação que ele precisa decidir se o elemento deve mudar de lugar ou não. Para isso ele passará dois valores, o elemento atual e o próximo, e aí você os compara como quiser. No exemplo eles foram recebidos pelos parâmetros `a` e `b`.

Para informar a situação de um elemento em relação ao outro você deve escrevê-la de forma que retorne 0 se os elementos forem iguais. Retornará um valor positivo maior que 0 se o primeiro elemento (o `a`) for maior que o segundo (o `b`), e um número negativo se o primeiro for menor que o segundo. Lembrando que o critério é seu, você pode fazer qualquer maluquice se quiser. E note que não precisa ser 1 ou -1, só precisa ser positivo ou negativo (ou neutro).

O código específico do exemplo está usando um [operador condicional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4907/101) para tomar essa decisão. Está devolvendo 1 quando o `a` é menor que `b`. Parece estranho sabendo do que está no parágrafo anterior, mas é assim mesmo, você quer uma classificação em ordem inversa, então tem que inverter o valor. E a função não se importou se é igual, trata como se o primeiro fosse maior que o segundo mesmo sendo igual, e devolve -1.

Se quiser classificar de forma aleatória (só para mostrar que pode usar qualquer critério mesmo:

```js
notas = [7, 6, 10];
notas.sort((a, b) => Math.random() - 0.5);
console.log(notas);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/SortExample.js).

Isso poderá retornar um valor positivo ou negativo de cada passo, por isso fica aleatório.

Em alguns casos pode fazer algo mais complexo, por exemplo pegar um dos membros de um objeto para usar como comparação. Vamos dizer que um objeto tenha uma propriedade chamada `idade`, você pode classificar a lista de objetos de acordo com a idade dos participantes. Você receberá o objeto todo e tem que pegar a propriedade para fazer a comparação, aí fica igual a como se tivesse recebido um número de forma direta.