# Diferenças entre definir métodos de objetos utilizando arrow function e function expression

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, método, objetos

Sobre métodos "chamáveis" de fora de objetos, eu posso dizer que essas três formas abaixo agem da mesma forma dentro do meu código?

Exemplos:

```
var barquinho = {
  pedro: () => {
    console.log("a");
  },
  tiago: function() {
    console.log("b");
  },
  joao() {
    console.log("c");
  }
};
```

Essas são as formas que eu conheço para se definir métodos dentro de objetos.

Gostaria de saber quais são as diferenças entre as três formas acima, visto que uso a mesma forma para os invocar:

```
barquinho.pedro();
barquinho.tiago();
barquinho.joao();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### "Métodos" como *arrow functions*

A diferença é que, no primeiro caso, você está utilizando uma *arrow function* para definir o método. Consulte [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114367/69296) e a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) para saber mais sobre esse tipo de função.

Em resumo, a *arrow function* não tem o seu próprio `this` *binding*, isto é, não possui o `this` associado ao objeto a qual está contida (lembrar que toda função está associada a algum objeto). Exatamente por isso não faz muito sentido utilizá-la para definir um método, uma vez que, por definição, métodos sempre estão associados a ideia de algum "objeto" ou "instância". Basicamente, o `this` da *arrow function* será herdado do escopo léxico imediatamente superior.

```js
const obj = {
  arrow: () => {
    console.log(this.toString()); // [object Window]
    console.log(this === obj); // false
    console.log(this === window); // true
  }
};

obj.arrow();
```

Como utilizamos uma *arrow function* para definir o "método" `arrow`, este herdará o valor `this` do escopo léxico acima. Como objetos não têm escopo léxico, o `this` refere-se ao escopo global, que em *browsers* é `window`. [Vale observar também que, no modo estrito, o comportamento do `this` global é um pouco diferente.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3752/69296)

Justamente por isso não vale a pena utilizar *arrow functions* em todo lugar, ao contrário do que muita gente parece fazer. Qual o sentido de usar *arrow function* para definir um método, sendo que você não poderá sequer de acessar, através do `this`, outras propriedades desse objeto? Justamente por isso coloquei o termo "métodos" entre aspas no título desta seção.

### Métodos com *function expression* e a nova notação

Nos outros dois exemplos, utiliza-se [expressão de função](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) para definir os métodos. Nesse caso, o `this` refere-se ao objeto no qual os métodos estão contidos. Vejamos:

```js
const obj = {
  a: function() {
    console.log(this.toString()); // [object Object]
    console.log(this === obj); // true
    console.log(this === window); // false
  },
  
  b() {
    console.log(this.toString()); // [object Object]
    console.log(this === obj); // true
    console.log(this === window); // false
  }
};

obj.a();
console.log('---');
obj.b();
```

A única diferença entre `a` e `b`, no exemplo acima, é que `b` utiliza uma notação introduzida no ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) para facilitar a definição de *function expressions* em objetos. Embora seja um açúcar sintático, existe uma sutil diferença:

Ao contrário de definir uma função utilizando a notação "antiga" (no exemplo acima, método `a`) de expressão de função, ao utilizar a *nova* sintaxe (no exemplo acima, método `b`), não pode-se utilizar a função como construtora.

Desse modo, poderíamos, em tese, fazer isto:

```
const obj = {
  functionExpression: function() { /* ... */ }
}; 

new obj.functionExpression(); // Totalmente válido!
```

No entanto, funções definidas com a nova notação não são construíveis:

```
const obj = {
  newMethodDefinitionSyntax: function() { /* ... */ }
}; 

new obj.newMethodDefinitionSyntax(); // TypeError: obj.newMethodDefinitionSyntax is not a constructor
```

Justamente por isso, ao utilizar a nova notação, propriedades como `prototype` (não confundir com `__proto__`) não estarão definidas, já que só fazem sentido no caso de funções construtoras.

Fora isso, a diferença é meramente sintática. Saiba mais sobre esse açúcar sintático na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions).