# Qual a diferença entre definir uma propriedade de um objeto como função ou já passar o parênteses direto?

Tags: javascript, node.js, objetos

Qual a diferença entre as propriedades store e store2?

```
const MyObject = {
    store1(req, res) {
       console.log(req, res)
    },
    store2: function(req, res){
       console.log(req, res)
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá, Heber! Marquei a sua pergunta como duplicata pois já foi respondida aqui no site em uma outra pergunta (muito parecida, inclusive). Mas, em resumo, entre os dois que você pontuou, **não há diferença**. O primeiro é apenas açúcar sintático do segundo. Essa nova notação foi introduzida no ECMAScript 2015 (ES6). Consulte a [resposta indicada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/472205/69296) na mensagem de duplicata para mais detalhes.

Comment: @LuizFelipe, teste isso: `console.log(MyObject.store1.hasOwnProperty('prototype'));
console.log(MyObject.store2.hasOwnProperty('prototype'));`.Acho que é uma *peculiaridade* do JS pois não encontrei documentação sobre esse comportamento.

Comment: Realmente interessante, @AugustoVasques! Nunca tinha testado isso (e acabei percebendo uma outra diferença bem sutil também). Vou investigar mais a fundo porque fiquei curioso para entender esse comportamento. Obrigado por apontar – como sempre pontuações muito interessantes. :)

Comment: Mas curioso é que: `MyObject.store1.__proto__=== MyObject.store2.__proto__` dá `true`... E, embora é o que eu realmente esperava, fica estranho (acho eu) tendo em vista esse comentário acima. Estou tentando achar a diferença que justifica isso... Talvez esteja a nível de _spec_.

Comment: Ah, achei. Está documentado **[aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#method_definitions_are_not_constructable)** (deve ter na _spec_ também, mas fiquei com preguiça de procurar lá :P). Sintaticamente falando é a mesma coisa (conforme a própria documentação referida indica mais em cima), mas como a nova sintaxe não pode ser utilizada como função construtora, não faz sentido ter a propriedade `prototype` (que, como sabemos, é utilizada no `__proto__` das instâncias criadas pelo construtor). cc: @AugustoVasques