# O this está assumindo o valor de Window

Tags: javascript, protótipo, this

Eu não sei o que tem de errado neste código. Dentro do construtor da função `EvilCircle`, o `this` funciona direitinho, mas em `EvilCircle.prototype.draw` não funciona. Parece que ele se transforma no Window.

```js
function Shape(x, y, velX, velY, exists) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.velX = velX;
  this.velY = velY;
  this.exists = exists;
}

// EvilCircle
function EvilCircle(x, y, exists) {
  Shape.call(this, x, y, 20, 20, exists);
  this.color = 'white';
  this.size = 10;
}
EvilCircle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
EvilCircle.prototype.constructor = EvilCircle;

// Draw;
EvilCircle.prototype.draw = () => {
  console.log(this);
};
```

Comment: Conforme explicado nas perguntas sugeridas acima (em especial [nesta resposta](/a/143974/112052)), o problema é que o `this` tem comportamento diferente em _arrow functions_ e `function`'s - o que é mais um motivo para não sair usando sem motivo. Tenho visto muita gente que acha que *arrow functions* são "o jeito novo" (ou pior, uns acham que é o único jeito) de criar funções, quando na verdade o uso de `function` ainda se mostra necessário... O importante é saber a diferença, as implicações, e avaliar quando usar um ou outro

Comment: Aaaata. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Isso está acontecendo porque você está utilizando uma *arrow function*, cujo `this` *binding* possui funcionamento léxico. Isso significa que o `this` não irá se referir à instância de `EvilCircle`, mas sim ao `this` do escopo superior que, nesse caso, é `window`.

Saiba mais [nesta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/114371/69296). A [**documentação**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) também pode ser clarificadora nessa matéria.

Para corrigir, então, utilize uma expressão de função:

```
EvilCircle.prototype.draw = function() {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(this instanceof EvilCircle); //=> true
};
```

---

Sobre programação orientada a objetos em JavaScript, o funcionamento sempre será [prototípico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42962/69296). Mas vale a pena utilizar a [nova sintaxe de classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), introduzida no ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) para simplificar o seu código, principalmente na parte relacionada à herança.

```
class Shape {
  constructor(x, y, velX, velY, exists) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.velX = velX;
    this.velY = velY;
    this.exists = exists;
  }
}

class EvilCircle extends Shape {
  constructor(x, y, exists) {
    // Chama o construtor da classe pai:
    super(this, x, y, 20, 20, exists);

    this.color = 'white';
    this.size = 10;
  }

  draw() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Esclareceu tudo :)